# How to convert ternary to if/else condition

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, shortcut

This is what my ternary looks like now, but I'd like to see how this looks as an if/else block

```
function showResultBox(v){     
  v ? searchResultBox() : hideBox()    
}
```

Comment: `if (v) { searchResultBox(); } else { hideBox(); }`

Comment: [Conditional Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 1):

A [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) is way of formatting a conditional that is limited to just an `if` | `else`. That is, there is no room for any `else if` blocks.

Here is what's happening in `v ? searchResultBox() : hideBox()`:

```
                        1          2                3
```

1. Evaluate `v` for [truthiness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).
2. If `v` is truthy, call the `searchResultBox` function.
3. Otherwise, call the `hideBox` function

As a non-ternary conditional, your example would look like this:

```js
if (v) {
  searchResultBox();
} else {
  hideBox();
}
```

You can experiment with the following examples ([fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/w5s0b5qh/)) to get a better feel for what's going on:

```
true ? console.log("stark") : console.log("baratheon")
false ? console.log("stark") : console.log("baratheon")
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post.

Comment: Happy to help; I've added a little more context. Let me know if you think it could benefit from more elaboration

Comment: Hi Jordan, I have a ternory condition. Can you please convert it into if condition. Here is the condition 

(s.outerHeight() > $(window).outerHeight()) && (b = !1), b && a >= r 
 ? (v && o.css({ height: u }), s.addClass("following")) 
 : (v && o.css({ height: "auto" }), s.removeClass("following"));

here s, b, a, r, v, o are variables. Can you please help me?